# How do I launch Powershell locally on NanoServer?

Tags: python, powershell, nano-server

I have created NS image with 'Development' switch using Windows 2016 Technical Preview 5. I am deploying the NS image onto a physical machine.I want to run Python interactive shell on local Powershell but it appears that there is no local PS console on NanoServer.

Comment: **Update** : I found it ..With '-Development' option if we build NS image we could see local Powershell console.

Answer (score 0):

Nano Server is designed to be administered remotely, the local 'console' only allows you to set firewall rules and network config.

You'll need to do everything via a remote session with Nano Server. If that's not suitable for you the only option is to move to the full Server 2016 OS instead as this has the standard local console with GUI.